# Failed to compile gtkmm-3.10.1

Tags: linux, compilation, gtk, gentoo

Hi I am trying to compile inkscpae but it needs gtkmm,
So I downloaded it and tried to compile it but I get this error

./configure --prefix=$HOME/Local/gtkm CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/Local/gc-7.4.2/include -I$HOME/Local/gtkmm/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/Local/gcFiles/lib -L$HOME/Local/gtkmm/lib"

```
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I../.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"gdkmm\" -DGDKMM_BUILD=1 -pthread -pthread -I/home/users/oren.amsalem/Local/gtkmm/include/giomm-2.4 -I/home/users/oren.amsalem/Local/gtkmm/lib/giomm-2.4/include -I/home/users/oren.amsalem/Local/gtkmm/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/home/users/oren.amsalem/Local/gtkmm/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib64/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib64/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/home/users/oren.amsalem/Local/gc-7.4.2/include -I/home/users/oren.amsalem/Local/gtkmm/include -Wall -g -O2 -MT window.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/window.Tpo -c window.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/window.o
window.cc: In static member function 'static void Gdk::Window::constrain_size(const Geometry&, guint, int, int, int&, int&)':
window.cc:950:117: error: invalid conversion from 'guint {aka unsigned int}' to 'GdkWindowHints' [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdktestutils.h:26:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:55,
                 from ../gdkmm/color.h:36,
                 from ../gdkmm/dragcontext.h:30,
                 from ../gdkmm/window.h:31,
                 from window.cc:9:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkwindow.h:1049:12: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void gdk_window_constrain_size(GdkGeometry*, GdkWindowHints, gint, gint, gint*, gint*)' [-fpermissive]
Makefile:572: recipe for target 'window.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [window.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/users/oren.amsalem/Local/gtkmm-3.10.1/gdk/gdkmm'
Makefile:744: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/users/oren.amsalem/Local/gtkmm-3.10.1'
Makefile:529: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any Idea what is the problem?

I don't see a dependency problem.

Thank you,
Oren.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your GTK+ version is too newer or older than your gtkmm version. You seem to be using gtkmm-3.10.1 so your GTK+ version should be GTK+ 3.10.something. If your GTK+ is newer then try using the corresponding gtkmm version. Of course, that might be difficult if it means that you need to update other dependencies yourself - building from source is always difficult.

These small changes in the GTK+ C API are not unusual and get noticed more by C++ compilers. But we keep gtkmm in sync with GTK+.